# Registering Javascript / CSS files within Partial Views with Output Caching only once

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I would like to create partial views which would require the inclusion of Javascript/CSS files in order to function properly.  The same partial view can be included multiple times within a page and hence if I put the embedding of the Javascript/CSS files within the Partial View HTML content, such files will be embedded N amount of times.  I would want such files to be embedded only once.

Also, such Partial Views are being rendered using the `Html.Action` method so as to make use of output caching so the Action method will not execute all the time.

My idea was to register the javascript/css files within the Partial View with with some controller which manages such embedding and then outputs them at the scripts section of the page, at the bottom before the end `</body>` tag but since the Actions will be cached, such code is not guaranteed to be executed but can be loaded from Cache.

Any suggestions for best practices for such scenario?

Answer (score 2):

You could define 2 custom helpers:

```
public static class HtmlExtensions
{
    public static IHtmlString RenderRegisteredScripts(this HtmlHelper htmlHelper)
    {
        var ctx = htmlHelper.ViewContext.HttpContext;
        var registeredScripts = ctx.Items["_scripts_"] as Stack<string>;
        if (registeredScripts == null || registeredScripts.Count < 1)
        {
            return null;
        }
        var sb = new StringBuilder();
        foreach (var script in registeredScripts)
        {
            var scriptBuilder = new TagBuilder("script");
            scriptBuilder.Attributes["type"] = "text/javascript";
            scriptBuilder.Attributes["src"] = script;
            sb.AppendLine(scriptBuilder.ToString(TagRenderMode.Normal));
        }
        return new HtmlString(sb.ToString());
    }

    public static void RegisterScript(this HtmlHelper htmlHelper, string script)
    {
        var ctx = htmlHelper.ViewContext.HttpContext;
        var urlHelper = new UrlHelper(htmlHelper.ViewContext.RequestContext);
        var registeredScripts = ctx.Items["_scripts_"] as Stack<string>;
        if (registeredScripts == null)
        {
            registeredScripts = new Stack<string>();
            ctx.Items["_scripts_"] = registeredScripts;
        }
        var src = urlHelper.Content(script);
        if (!registeredScripts.Contains(src))
        {
            registeredScripts.Push(src);
        }
    }
}
```

and then have a `_Layout.cshtml` in which you are calling the `RenderRegisteredScripts` helper at the end:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>@ViewBag.Title</title>
    <link href="@Url.Content("~/Content/Site.css")" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
</head>
<body>
    @RenderBody()
    <script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery-1.7.1.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
    @RenderSection("Scripts", required: false)
    @Html.RenderRegisteredScripts()
</body>
</html>
```

Now you could have a view which renders some partial as many times as you like:

```
@for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
{
    @Html.Partial("_Foo")    
}

@Html.Action("Bar")
```

and inside this partial (`_Foo.cshtml`) use the `RegisterScript` helper to register dependent scripts for this partial:

```
@{Html.RegisterScript("~/scripts/foo.js");}
```

Now when you look at the generated HTML markup the script is included only once:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title></title>
    <link href="/Content/Site.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
</head>
<body>
    <script src="/Scripts/jquery-1.7.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="/scripts/foo.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What about when you load a partial view through the `Html.Action` with `[OutputCaching]` tag and hence no code is executed but outputted from the cache, no code is executed and such a script won't be registered and hence not outputted?